# Rouché's Theroem for an annulus $1 < \lvert z\rvert < 2$

Tags: complex-analysis

How many roots of $z^5 + 4z^2+1$ are in $1 < \lvert z\rvert < 2$.

**Attempt**

For the disk $\lvert z\rvert < 2$, there are $5$ zeros in the disk $\lvert z\rvert < 2$ because
$$\begin{gathered}f(z) = z^5\\ h(z) = 4z^2+1\end{gathered}$$
and 
$\lvert f(z)\rvert = 32 > \lvert h(z)\rvert = 4\lvert z^2\rvert + 1 = 17,$

and for the disk $\lvert z\rvert > 1$ there are $2$ zeros in the disk $\lvert z\rvert > 1$ because 
$$\begin{gathered}f(z) = 4z^2\\ h(z) = z^5+1\end{gathered}$$
and $\lvert f(z)\rvert = \lvert 4z^2\rvert = 4 > \lvert h(z)\rvert = \lvert z^5+1\rvert = \lvert z^5\rvert + 1 = 2$,

so there are $5 - 2 = 3$ zeros in the annulus $1 < \lvert z\rvert < 2$?

Answer (score 2):

You have a few glitches in the write-up, but essentially it's right.

You typo'ed $\lvert z\rvert > 1$ where you meant $\lvert z\rvert < 1$, and your estimates ought to read

$$\lvert f(z)\rvert = 32 > 17 = 4\lvert z^2\rvert + 1 \geqslant \lvert h(z)\rvert$$

resp.

$$\lvert f(z)\rvert = \lvert 4z^2\rvert = 4 > 2 = \lvert z^5\rvert+1 \geqslant \lvert z^5+1\rvert = \lvert h(z)\rvert.$$

In general, the inequality $\lvert z^5+1\rvert \leqslant \lvert z^5\rvert + 1$ is strict, ditto for $\lvert 4z^2+1\rvert \leqslant 4\lvert z^2\rvert + 1$, so the "$=$" you wrote is incorrect.